# Simple Angular SPA in ASP .NET 5 - getting blank page on startup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-route

I'm attempting to set up a very simple Angular single-page-application in ASP .NET 5.  I've begun with an empty project - the only angular dependency at the moment is ngRoute.

**The problem:**

> When I run the project, I get a blank page in my browser - with no errors in the developer console.

**EDIT**

I removed the `[]` from the `angular.module('app', []).controller` as suggested but now an error is thrown:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a

I'm using npm, bower, and grunt - but I don't think they have anything to do with the problem.

Here's what the project structure looks like:

[image]

Here's the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- angular -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- app -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the app.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'Views/home.html',
                controller: 'home'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
})();
```

Here's the home.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app').controller('home', function controller($scope) {
        $scope.title = 'Home';
    });
})();
```

Here's the home.html:

```
<div ng-controller="home">
    {{ title }}
</div>
```

**Why do I get a blank page and not the text "Home" rendered on screen?**

The app.js under wwwroot contains all of the contents of the Scripts folder - with the app.js contents written first.  Here's the gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Load grunt plugins from npm.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");

    // Configure plugins.
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Combine and minify all of the javascript files from the Scripts folder into the wwwroot 
        // folder, making sure the app.js is placed at the beginning.
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: { "wwwroot/app.js": ["Scripts/App/app.js", "Scripts/**/*.js"] }
            }
        },

        // Re-run the uglify task when any of the files in the Scripts folder change.
        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ["Scripts/**/*.js"],
                tasks: ["uglify"]
            }
        }
    });

    // Define tasks.
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["uglify", "watch"]);
};
```

I can see that the `angular.js`, `angular-route.js`, and `app.js` have loaded correctly in the browser.  Here's the contents of the "uglified" app.js:

```
!function(){"use strict";var a=angular.module("app",["ngRoute"]);a.config(function(a){a.when("/",{templateUrl:"Views/home.html",controller:"home"}).otherwise({redirectTo:"/"})})}(),function(){"use strict";angular.module("app",[]).controller("home",function(a){a.title="Home"})}();
```

Comment: If you open the dev consortium do you see any errors?

Comment: "with no errors in the developer console".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claies is right when it comes to app initialization, but there is another thing.

You problem is much more complicated than you think. You are using `uglifyjs`, which changes names of variables in controller arguments. You need to use `ngannotate` in `gruntfile.js` or switch to longer controller definition.

This is brief explanation:
`uglify` wants to make your JS files lighter and changes it from this:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', function($scope, service) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
  service.fnc();
});
```

To this:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', function(a,b) {
  a.greeting = 'Hola!';
  b.fnc();
});
```

This causes problems for angular because it does not know what `a` is.

If you want to solve it without changing your controllers, you can use `ngannotate` task. Alternative way is changing controller's definition:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', 'service', function($scope, service) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
  service.fnc();
}]);
```

Uglify will transform that to:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', 'service', function(a, b) {
  a.greeting = 'Hola!';
  b.fnc();
}]);
```

NOTE: Please have in mind that using `ngannotate` is probably better way, beacause you will not face same problems with 3rd party services etc.

Comment: The uglify has options, one of which is "mangle: false" which I will use for now - until I get ngAnnotate in there.

Answer (score 2):

Your home.js has a subtle bug.  You are re-declaring your `app` module, which is removing all the route configuration.

`angular.module('app', []).controller...` is the **setter** syntax for a module. Instead, you should use `angular.module('app').controller` **getter** syntax, to avoid re-declaring the module.

Comment: Thanks, but I changed it to that because without the `[]` I get this error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a` which I guess is the real issue then.